# getting the size of the file contents in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, file-io

Am writing an application for iphone to read a text file using NSData.

```
NSFileHandle *fileRead;

// this may lead to crash or memory issue, if the file size is about 10 mb or more

NSData *data =   [fileRead readDataOfLength:(entire contents of the file)];
```

For example, if the file size is 8 kb, we can reading it in 8 iterations by 1kb per cycle.

Before reading the file, how can we find the size of the file contents.so that we can write the code in a optimized way to read the file effectively?

plz give me your suggestions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone has all of the standard POSIX APIs, so you can use stat("file.txt", &st), where st is a "struct stat". The "st.st_size" member will give you the file size in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really wanting to read the entire file, just use `readDataToEndOfFile` and don't worry about determining the length beforehand.

From an NSFileHandle, you can find the length by first `seekToEndOfFile` and then `offsetInFile`. If you have the actual file name, you could use NSFileManager's `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` to retrieve the length (as with C's `stat`) instead. Or, for that matter, you could actually use `stat`, or `fstat` on the file descriptor returned by NSFileHandle's `fileDescriptor` method.